# How to reset time for different dates in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the input df below, I need to set the time to 00:00:00 of the column "TimeLeft" as soon as the day change. For example,

input df:

```
   TimeLeft              colum_B  ProgPerc  id_B      ts_B
0  2017-04-27T00:01:12   B        97.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:36:48
1  2017-04-27T00:00:12   B        98.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:37:48
2  2017-04-26T23:58:24   B        99.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:38:48
3  2017-04-26T23:57:45   B        100.0     id1       2017-04-27T01:39:36
```

output df:

```
   TimeLeft              colum_B  ProgPerc  id_B      ts_B
0  2017-04-27T00:01:12   B        97.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:36:48
1  2017-04-27T00:00:12   B        98.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:37:48
2  2017-04-26T00:00:00   B        99.0      id1       2017-04-27T01:38:48
3  2017-04-26T00:00:00   B        100.0     id1       2017-04-27T01:39:36
```

Any help woul dbe very appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help. Best Regards, C

Comment: Why would time left be 0 on the day before? This looks like a countdown? I don't think there's enough info to answer this. The time and progress percentage seem to go in opposite directions.

Comment: If you are looking for the replace method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) I can write something up for you

Comment: Many Thanks Liam Healy. Yes, it would be very supportive. My approach that I trying to implement is to add an extra column ["day"] and then when the difference is less than zero then set the corresponding time to 00:00:00.

Comment: @roganjosh: the input df is the output of a processing where the date does not matter. I just need to make sure that the time is set to 00:00:00 as I described above. Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: But your example doesn't make much sense. So, the latest date should be recorded to 1 min accuracy and  any other date should to be set to midnight of the date it has?

Comment: Ok. I will try to explain here a bit more: raw 0 and row 1 they have the same day. For them the corresponding time should not be reset. In contrast, when comparing row 1 and row 2, the day changed therefore the time should be reset to 00:00:00 from the row 2 up to the end, row 3.

Comment: or simple: how can I apply datetime.replace when the codition holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Here is the solution:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  filepath="/home/SERILOCAL/c.allocca/Desktop/MantaData/test1/1490022000_1.csv"
  df = pd.read_csv(filepath) #your input data saved here

  df["ts_B_day"]=df["ts_B"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").date().day)    
  df["TimeLeft_day"]=df["TimeLeft"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").date().day)    

 def replace_time(row): 
    date_=datetime.datetime.strptime(row['TimeLeft'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").date()
    end_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date_, datetime.time(00, 00,00))
    end_time = end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')    
    return end_time

df['TimeLeft'] = df.apply(lambda row: replace_time(row) if row['ts_B_day'] != row['TimeLeft_day']  else (row['TimeLeft']), axis=1)
print(df.to_string())
```